# Connection to FTP Server hangs on Mac

Tags: macos, ftp

I'm trying to test a function connecting to a FTP server. When running the tests on Linux they work fine, but on Mac i can only run them once after starting it, after this one time the test will hang on this function:

```
def test_ftp(ftpserver):
    with FTP() as f:
        f.connect("localhost", port=ftpserver.server_port)
        f.login("USER", "PASSWORD")
        f.cwd("/")
        f.mkd("FOO")
        f.quit()
```

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/oz123/pytest-localftpserver to run the FTP server.
I checked the port after running the tests, it is not used anymore. 
Can anybody explain to me, why this is happening?